# using command line argument while using expect

Tags: scripting, expect

Hi I am using expect to mput a file to a remote machine.I am passing the filename as a command line argument to the script.But error is throwing from the line

```
send -- "mput $1\r"
```

My code is as follows:

```
set timeout 1000
spawn ftp $ipaddress
expect "Name "
send -- "$username\r"
expect "Password"
send -- "$passwd\r"
expect "ftp>"
send -- "mput $1\r"//error thrown from this line
expect "mput $1? "
send -- "y\r"
expect "ftp>"
send -- "bye\r"
```

Could anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `$1` with `[lindex $argv 0]`. The `$argc` variable tells the number of given arguments.